# Python: Add a Key-Value pair when a condition is true

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

Starting point are the following lists of dicts:

```
product = [
    {'_id': '5678', 'variantIds':[{'id':'1'},{'id':'2'},{'id':'3'}]},
    {'_id': '1234', 'variantIds':[{'id':'1'},{'id':'2'},{'id':'3'}]}  
    ]

inventoryItem = [
    {'_id': 'a6fdcf69', 'productId': '1234', 'variants': [{'variantId': '1', 'quantity': 0}, {'variantId': '2', 'quantity': 100}]},
    {'_id': 'a6fdcf70', 'productId': '5678', 'variants': [{'variantId': '1', 'quantity': 0}, {'variantId': '2', 'quantity': 199}, {'variantId': '3', 'quantity': 299}]},
    {'_id': 'a6fdcf77', 'productId': '9999', 'variants': [{'variantId': '1', 'quantity': 1111}, {'variantId': '2', 'quantity': 2222}, {'variantId': '3', 'quantity': 3333}]}   
    ]
```

what i want is to add the key-value pair 'quantity':'value of quantity' to the first list of products. specifically i want to add it the the sub-list of dicts 'variantIds'. And I only want to add it when product[_'id] == inventoryItem['productId'] AND product['variantIds']['id] == inventoryItem['variants']['variantId'], so that e get the following output:

```
product = [
    {'_id': '5678', 'variantIds':[{'id':'1', 'stockQuantity':0},{'id':'2', 'stockQuantity':199},{'id':'3', 'stockQuantity':299}]},
    {'_id': '1234', 'variantIds':[{'id':'1', 'stockQuantity':0},{'id':'2', 'stockQuantity':100},{'id':'3', 'stockQuantity':0}]}  
    ]
```

i can loop and add everything as long as the order in one list is corresponding to the order in the other list. but if it's not the case, what could be, i struggle with addressing the right index of the second list. how do you do that?

i think here is my closest try. but i already struggle on line 2, because i do not know the corresponding index in the inventoryItem List:

```
for i in product:

    if i['_id'] == inventoryItem['productId']:

        for j in i['variantIds']:
                
            if j['id'] == inventoryItem['variants']['variantId']:

                j['stock'] = inventoryItem['variants']['quantity']

print (product)
```

Comment: Do all items of product list lie in inventoryItem?

Comment: Please paste the code which you have written which is not working correctly.

Comment: @RishabhKumar: yes, for every product._id there is a inventoryItem.ProductId, same goes for the variantIds and variants. but the order does not correspond from one to the other list. i could e.g. order both lists to get the right order ?!

Comment: @lllrnr101: i added my approach which is clearly wrong because of the unknown index in the inventoryItem List.

Comment: @boese in that case, in my code below you may not need the `try` `except` statements, but I recommended still keep them.

Comment: @RishabhKumar thx and yes i will certainly keep those!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
product = [
    {'_id': '5678', 'variantIds':[{'id':'1'},{'id':'2'},{'id':'3'}]},
    {'_id': '1234', 'variantIds':[{'id':'1'},{'id':'2'},{'id':'3'}]}  
    ]

inventoryItem = [
    {'_id': 'a6fdcf69', 'productId': '1234', 'variants': [{'variantId': '1', 'quantity': 0}, {'variantId': '2', 'quantity': 100}]},
    {'_id': 'a6fdcf70', 'productId': '5678', 'variants': [{'variantId': '1', 'quantity': 0}, {'variantId': '2', 'quantity': 199}, {'variantId': '3', 'quantity': 299}]},
    {'_id': 'a6fdcf77', 'productId': '9999', 'variants': [{'variantId': '1', 'quantity': 1111}, {'variantId': '2', 'quantity': 2222}, {'variantId': '3', 'quantity': 3333}]}   
    ]



for prod in product:
    try:
        loc = [i['productId'] for i in inventoryItem].index(prod['_id'])
        variantList = inventoryItem[loc]['variants']
        for item in prod['variantIds']:
            try:
                subloc = [i['variantId'] for i in variantList].index(item['id'])
                quantity = variantList[subloc]['quantity']
            except:
                quantity = 0
            item.update({'stockQuantity':quantity})
    except Exception as e:
        pass
        print(e.args) # you can remove this line, if this disturbs your output

print(product)
```

Now this may not be the best way to do it, but its pretty straightforward.
This is based on what I understood about the structure of the data. Maybe there is more to the data, and based on that it can be optimized further. But it works on the example set you provided.

What this does is, it grabs items (dictionaries) from product list. Searches for similar id in inventoryItem. Grabs that index (of the dictionary) inside inventoryItem. And then just scans to proper places in that entry of inventoryItem and then updates the product based on that.

Note : I have assumed here that there is no specific order to anything.

If there is an explanation necessary to any part, let me know.

Comment: this is awesome! exactly what i was looking for.. thx! i changed some variant IDs and it still does the job.

Comment: How would you delete a dict from the variants-list when stockQuantity is 0 (zero) ? so productID 1234 would have only one variant with variantID 2 and stockQuantity 100: `{'_id': '1234', 'variantIds':[{'id':'2', 'stockQuantity':100}]}`

Comment: change the `item.update({'stockQuantity':quantity})` to `item.update({'stockQuantity':quantity}) if quantity else pass` , this would do the job without deleting anything

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that you mixed lists and dictionnary so you need to access to the lists of variantIds. You can do it as follow I think :

```
for i in range(len(product)):
   for j in range(len(product[0]['variantIds'])):
     product[i]['variantIds'][j]['stockQuantity'] = 0

print(product)
```

Output:

```
[{'_id': '5678', 'variantIds': [{'id': '1', 'stockQuantity': 0}, {'id': '2', 'stockQuantity': 0}, ...
```

Comment: thanks @babapt, but that didn't solve my problem :-) index i or j of "product" does not necesarily correspond to the index of "inventoryItem". i need to find the index of the inventory where product._id = inventory.productId.